# Enable Gigabit Ethernet on a Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: networking, pi-3b+

I'm using a 3B+ rev 1.2 with a wired connection through a [CAT7 Ethernet cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11801#CAT7). Using `speedtest` I realised that I wasn't getting upload speeds higher than ~95Mbps, so I did a bit of research.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

It doesn't seem to support `1000BaseT` connections, even though this version is [expected to support it](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-gigabit-networking).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what upload speeds do you get on other computers? What's the output of `grep Model /proc/cpuinfo` ... or `cat /proc/device-tree/model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a Raspberry 3B, not a 3B+.

‍♂️

Comment: Also keep in mind that even on a Pi 3B+ (which technically has a 1000baseT port), the ethernet is tied to the USB 2 bus and USB 2 doesn't support those speeds.  So you get better than 100baseT but not nearly what true 1000baseT can handle.   Pi 4B has true 1000baseT support.

Comment: 480Mbit/sec is the max throughput on a USB 2.0 hub and you share that bandwidth with other devices on the same USB hub.